# Django rest framework - Creating and returning multiple instances of an object instead of one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What I'm doing is posting a list of primary keys with other data to an endpoint and I'm creating an instance of an object per id that is in the list. The problem is that I want to then return all the objects I created but only one instance of the object is expected so it doesn't work.

The data I'm posting to /convo/:id/members/ looks like this:

```
{
  member_ids = [5,1,2,6]
}
```

Then in the view I'm passing the current user to my serializer (needed for the object I'm creating because it has an added_by field.
I'm doing this by overriding perform_create. It looks ca like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
  convo = Conversation.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk])
  serializer.save(added_by = self.request.user, convo = convo)
```

Then I'm overriding the create method in the serializer, take each id in the data received and create a member in the conversation. This is how that looks like ca (pseudocode)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
  added_by = validated_data.pop('added_by')
  users = validated_data.pop('member_ids')
  convo = validated_data.pop('convo')
  added_members = []

 for u in users:
    added_members.append(ConvoMember.objects.create(convo = convo, user = u, added_by = added_by))

  return added_members // this fails because its expecting only one instance of ConvoMember
  // but i still need to be able to do this somehow.
```

How do I go about returning all of the objects i created instead of having to return only the last one or something?

Comment: `convo = x` where is `x` defined?

Comment: Its defined, this was just pseudocode, actually i'll add it to the question

Comment: Why not bulk_create these in perform_create, instead of using the serializer? Can even validate them with their serializer, and append to the bulk_create list after is_valid() is True, then return everything you want in the response